# Can I tag multiple artist in mp3 files from banshee?

Tags: banshee, mp3, mp3-tag

Can I tag mp3 file such a way that `banshee` or `rhythmbox` music player can recognize the multiple artist separately. Right now the different artist are showing together like `Arijit Singh & Harshjeep`. I mean banshee is recognizing the whole entry as a separate artist, not individual one. So I can't effectively filter music using artist's name.

Comment: Consider `easytag` to batch edit ID tags on mp3s. That's all it does, but it does it well. Create a copy of some of your music files to practice on. It's easy to change a whole lotta tags in a very short time.

Comment: I don't think there's such a feature (currently). You can choose one of the artists as a "main" one. The "main" artist's name you add it to the artist field of the track, the featured artists' names you write between parenthesis in the song title: `Artist: Arijit Singh, Title: TheSongTitle (feat. Harshjeep)`. Not optimal but close, I think.

Comment: @Marc I can edit tag, that is easy. My question was what delimiter should I use to separate different artist so that `rhythmbox` or `banshee` can recognize them separately.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer re: Rhythmbox, but this is a known bug in Banshee, and has been for some time.  There is no satisfactory workaround.  Banshee's behaviour is as follows:

If there are multiple Artist tags on a file (achievable with, *exempli gratia*, an external tag-editor) it will concatenate them, using a delimiter to treat them as a single tag.  As I recall, this delimiter is a semicolon, although I could be wrong (I don't actually have a local music library with which to check...).  Banshee will then treat the resultant text ("artista; artistb") as the artist tag.

When Banshee encounters an artist tag, including one it's just constructed, that contains a delimiter, it does no special processing on it at all and treats it as the single-artist artist tag.

Yes, it's a pain. No, I don't know what can be done about it.  Sorry.

Answer (score -3):

I don't know about you, but the thought of editing tags for several thousand tracks one by one is beyond what I'm willing to do. `easytag` has bulk editing which allows you to change one field of one or ten or a thousand tracks at once without disturbing any other tags.

[image]

Comment: Downvoting, admittedly some time later, because as far as I can tell this is an answer to a different question (one of editing metadata tags on many tracks, rather than of setting multiple artists on a single track, the latter being what the question was actually about).